# Rails Routes Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Need to generate the following routes as

```
/:owner_name/articles
/:articles/:id
/owners
/:owner_name
```

I have tried as,

```
resources :owners, param: :owner_name, path: '', shallow_path: "", only: [:index, :show] do
resources :articles, only: [:index,:show]
end
```

But I am not able to reproduce the same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best solution but you can try the following

```
resources :articles, only: :show
resources :owners, only: :index
resources :owners, param: :name, path: '', only: :show do
  resources :articles, only: :index
end
```

It produces

```
    Prefix     Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
   article     GET  /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#show
    owners     GET  /owners(.:format)               owners#index
owner_articles GET  /:owner_name/articles(.:format) articles#index
     owner     GET  /:name(.:format)                owners#show
```

**UPDATE**

The code above has `:name` parameter instead of `:owner_name` for `owners#show` route (if it does matter for you).
You can try to specify parameters manually like

```
resources :articles, only: :show
resources :owners, only: :index
get '/:owner_name', to: 'owners#show'
get '/:owner_name/articles', to: 'articles#index'
```

It will give you

```
 Prefix Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
article GET  /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#show
 owners GET  /owners(.:format)               owners#index
        GET  /:owner_name(.:format)          owners#show
        GET  /:owner_name/articles(.:format) articles#index
```